# How to prepare layout,drawable folders for 7",10" android tablets for both landscape and portrait?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have prepared my drawables for 7" tablets as (Nexus 7)

```
 drawable-large-hdpi-port
 layout-large-hdpi-port
```

I am getting errors while doing this. I didnt understand where I am doing wrong.

I want to prepare layouts for both landscape and portrait for both 7", 10" tablets

Answer (score 41):

The [recommended way](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/2CpwdBJ8e6B) is to use `layout-swxxdp` qualifier. If you need to differentiate landscape/portrait

```
res/layout-sw600dp/   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw600dp-port/   # For 7” tablets in portrait (600dp wide or bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp-port/  # For 10” tablets in portrait (720dp wide or bigger)
```

Comment: Why do you need -port suffix?

Comment: will this only work for screen size >= 7" ? will it be used for a 4" screen that is 600dp wide?

Comment: @Lester this is for portrait only - see here https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Answer (score 17):

try below :-

```
values-sw720dp  10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

values-sw600dp  7.0”     tablet 1024x600 mdpi

values-sw480dp      5.4” 480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp      5.1” 480x800 mdpi 

values-xhdpi          4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi          4.65” 720x1280 xhdpi 

values-hdpi            4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi            3.7” 480x854 hdpi

values-mdpi           3.2” 320x480 mdpi

values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

also see below :-

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You are naming the folders in the wrong way. In Android, there is a rule or order in which you name your resource folders. You should provide your qualifier names in that order.

Check this [documentation table on providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2). Your should name your folders in the order provided in the table.(Its better if you read the whole page, because it'll give you a better understanding in providing resources)

Here you should name the folders as

```
layout-large-port-hdpi
drawable-large-port-hdpi
```

For preparing the resource folders for tablets, you can use either the **screen size** attribute or **shortest width** attribute.

For e.g

If you use **screen size** attribute, you can name folders like

```
layout-large-... (for 7" devices)
layout-xlarge-... (for 10" devices)
```

I you use **shortest width** attribute, you can use

```
layout-sw600dp-... (for 7" devices)
layout-sw720dp-... (for 10" devices)
```

Remember shortest width attribute works only on devices from 3.2 (API 13).

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
Wrong: drawable-hdpi-port/
Correct: drawable-port-hdpi/
```

You can see this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules)