# Android Developing for Tablet

Tags: android, layout, tablet

I’m developing an app for Android. I test my app in various phones and works great. I have my folders mdpi, hdpi..., xxxhdpi layouts and drawables too.
Now I’m facing the tablet problem. I test my app in Google Nexus 10 and the app not looks good. The tablet has a density of 2.0, so when I resize the component all is very small. I dony know if I have to add some other size folder layout or something like that.
How can I do to develop an app to work in tablets too? Something is missing and I can’t find it.

Comment: maybe this is a help: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prepare layout,drawable folders for 7",10" android tablets for both landscape and portrait?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647507/how-to-prepare-layout-drawable-folders-for-7-10-android-tablets-for-both-lands)

Answer (score 0):

You can add different layout resources depending on screen size, use these qualifiers:

```
res/layout-sw600dp/   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw600dp-port/   # For 7” tablets in portrait (600dp wide or bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp-port/  # For 10” tablets in portrait (720dp wide or bigger)
```

Refer to this question: [How to prepare layout,drawable folders for 7",10" android tablets for both landscape and portrait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647507/how-to-prepare-layout-drawable-folders-for-7-10-android-tablets-for-both-lands)

Comment: So, i have to create two more folder, for tablets of 7'' and 10''? Are tablets with more inches?

Comment: Also in the drawable folders too? Is there a way to use a drawable folder like xxhdpi so the images have more quality?

Comment: You'll probably want to add 4 new folders (each size in portrait and landscape).

Comment: You can still keep your images in whatever drawable folder they're in.

Comment: Only need landscape.

Comment: In that case, two folders.

Comment: The problem is when i desgin for example to tablet 10'', images are too small, how can i do to take images more big?

Comment: Use higher quality images in the appropriate folder. For example a Nexus 10 tablet has a xhdpi screen.

Comment: Yes i have, the problem is that when im designing in xml, all images are small, i have to resize it in code?

Comment: What is small? The size in layout or the quality? I don't really know what you mean.

Comment: The size in layout. When i move to the graphical layout everything is small.

Comment: So make them bigger using height and with attributes.

Comment: I have another problem, i ask for the dentisty, If density is 2.0 (xhdpi) and the screen size are not 1280 x 720 it calculates the new sizes of the components, That happens with my tablet because it has 2560 x 1600

Comment: Are you using density pixels in your layout?

Comment: Well then I don't really know what is wrong, sorry.